# Hyperbolic substitution for $\int\frac{dx}{x\sqrt{1-x^2}}$

Tags: calculus, integration, hyperbolic-functions

> Substitute $x=\sinh\theta$, $\cosh\theta$ or $\tanh\theta$. After integration change back to $x$.$$\int\frac{dx}{x\sqrt{1-x^2}}$$

Substituting $x=\tanh\theta$, we have
$$\begin{align}
\int\frac{dx}{x\sqrt{1-x^2}}&=\int\frac{\text{sech}^2\,\theta\,d\theta}{\tanh\theta\sqrt{1-\tanh^2\theta}}\\
&=\int\text{csch }\theta\,d\theta\\
&=-\ln|\text{csch }\theta+\text{coth }\theta|+C
\end{align}$$
Here comes the problem. We can substitute back $\text{coth }\theta=\frac1x$ but what do we have for $\text{csch }\theta$? We have $\text{csch}^2\,\theta=\coth^2\theta-1$, but neither $\sqrt{\coth^2\theta-1}$ nor $-\sqrt{\coth^2\theta-1}$ seems to be a one-off solution for $\text{csch }\theta$. How should we proceed?

Comment: I think $x = \sin t$ seems like a better substitute.

Comment: Just as a remark, the denominator of the integrand defines a plane curve called the [lemniscate of Gerono](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lemniscate_of_Gerono).  If you weren't required to make a hyperbolic substitution, I would have recommended one using the rational parametrization given on the linked page.

Comment: sinh or cosh of t seems better to substitute

Comment: @JackyChong With $x=\sin t$, the integral becomes a similar expression $-\ln|\csc t+\cot t|+C$. We have a similar problem, too, if we use a smiliar approach, i.e., $\cot^2 t=\csc^2 t-1$. We need a workaround to reach $\cot t=\frac{\sqrt{1-x^2}}{x}$. So, I think it is just a matter of preference. We are just more comfortable with trigonometric functions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$\DeclareMathOperator{\csch}{csch}
\DeclareMathOperator{\sech}{sech}$
Try
$$
\csch(\theta) = \frac{1}{\sinh(\theta)} = \frac{1/\cosh(\theta)}{\sinh(\theta)/\cosh(\theta)} = \frac{\sech(\theta)}{\tanh(\theta)} = \frac{\sqrt{1 - \tanh^2(\theta)}}{\tanh(\theta)} \, .
$$

How did I get this?  By cheating, basically.  The [Wikipedia page for the lemniscate of Gerono](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lemniscate_of_Gerono) has different parametrizations of the curve, one of which is $x = \cos(\varphi), y = \sin(\varphi) \cos(\varphi)$.  I used this parametrization to integrate, which gave me an expression involving $\frac{\sqrt{1 - x^2}}{x}$, which led me to this answer.

Comment: Nice trick. I read the page but do not know how to integrate using parametrization.

Comment: @W.Zhu You can interpret the given integral as the path integral $\int_C \frac{dx}{y}$ over the curve $C$ in the plane given by $y = x \sqrt{1-x^2}$ or better yet, $y^2 = x^2(1-x^2)$.  Then you substitute in the given parametrizations $x = \cos(\varphi), y = \sin(\varphi) \cos(\varphi)$.  In the end, it's equivalent to the substituting $x = \cos(\varphi)$ into the original integral.

Answer (score 0):

For positive $x$, another substitution that does not involve integrating $\csc{x}$ or $\operatorname{csch}{x}$ is a hyperbolic secant substitution (similar to a secant/cosecant substitution for $x^2-1$), where  $x=\operatorname{sech}{\theta}$, $dx=-\operatorname{sech}{\theta}\tanh{\theta}\,d\theta$, and $$\sqrt{1-x^2}=\sqrt{1-\operatorname{sech}^2{\theta}}=\sqrt{\tanh^2{\theta}}=\tanh{\theta}$$ since $\theta\geq0$ and $\tanh{x}$ is positive for that interval. $$\int{\frac{dx}{x\sqrt{1-x^2}}}=-\int{\frac{\operatorname{sech}{\theta}\tanh{\theta}}{\operatorname{sech}{\theta}\tanh{\theta}}d\theta}=-\int{d\theta}=-\theta+C$$ Substituting $x$ back gives $$-\operatorname{arsech}{x}+C\qquad x>0$$
For negative $x$, the substitution $x=-\operatorname{sech}{\theta}$ and $dx=\operatorname{sech}{\theta}\tanh{\theta}\,d\theta$ give $$-\operatorname{arsech}{\left(-x\right)}+C\qquad x<0$$ Combining the two branches gives $$-\operatorname{arsech}{\left|x\right|}+C$$